MS-Access 2016 Query String Criteria not Matching
I've been programming in VB, VBA, and Access for years, but this is a new one on me...
I have two table with identical field names that are of the short text data type (255). All other properties are the same. One table has distinct values in this field and the other has many of the same values. When I join the two tables in a query using this field, it will not return all the matching rows. For example:
SELECT tProjects.[Original Project]
   , tActivity.[Original Project]
FROM tProjects 
INNER JOIN tActivity ON tProjects.ID = tActivity.ProjectID
WHERE (((tProjects.[Original Project])="Mike Simpson:1967 Alfa Romeo Duetto Spider"));

I can open each table and copy/paste the string used in the criteria above. Both tables have the same string... "Mike Simpson:1967 Alfa Romeo Duetto Spider" in the [Original Project] field. If I copy and paste from one table and use this criteria only on that table, it returns values. However, I use the copied value on the other table which has the exact same text, text length, and field properties, it will not return a value. If I then open that second table and copy the text and use it for a string criteria in a select query against the second table, it returns records.
I also noticed a weird behavior in that using "Like" and a wild card at the end of the string only works if the string is less than 23 character.
This is messing up my database all of a sudden since I'm importing a text document and looping through to find new projects, i.e. - doesn't match an existing project. Suddenly I'm getting duplicate projects because of this.
I tried R&C of the front and back end databases, and even making the tables local.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
I tried everything I could think of.

You use join condition ON tProjects.ID = tActivity.ProjectID. So,table structure is different. One table has distinct values in - what field have distinct values? Second - you use INNER JOIN  - you want reduce result rows? Try LEFT JOIN. Pls, show table structure (minimal part) and data sample.

Appears to be issue with data not code so without reviewing actual data, hard to advise. I cannot replicate the 23 character limit issue. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.
